# How to write a function that only accepts a list of `Error string` `Results` in F# on the level of types?

Tags: f#

For example, given a `mergeErrors` function where input is always a list of `Error string`s,

```ml
let es = [ Error 1; Error 2; Error 3 ]

let mergeErrors<'a> (errors: Result<'a,int> list) : Result<'a,int list> =
    errors
    |> List.map (function | Error e -> e)
    |> Error

mergeErrors (es: Result<int,int> list)
//=> Error [1; 2; 3]
```

this will always blow up during runtime. Was wondering if there is a way to force failure to compile time?

---

#### Context

In my script, there is a `Result<'a, string> seq seq` type where each constituent `Result<'a, string> seq` needs to be flattened:

- if there are `Error`s, then `Ok`s can be discarded, and an `Error concatenatedStrings` should be returned
- if all is `Ok`, then they are merged depending of the shape of `'a`

My naive solution is to

```ml
let filterError (row: Result<'a, string> seq) =
    row 
    |> Seq.filter (function
        | Error _ -> true 
        | _       -> false)
    
let mergeErrors inputFromFilterError =
    // ...
```

This is almost surely the wrong approach (and found the F# For Fun and Profit's ["Map and Bind and Apply, Oh my!" series](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/#series-contents) while researching for an answer), but I'm still curious.

Comment: This can't be done in F# (or indeed most languages): the constructors are not treatable as a type in their own right. Some languages will allow you to express this (e.g. with refinement types), though I'm not aware of any where a discriminated union's constructors can be used in this way (not to say they don't exist). This in contrast to a straight union of types (a feature not supported by F#) where the union doesn't define its own well-named constructors, and the 'options' are necessarily types in their own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking at the top doesn't make sense on the face of it. Imagine you have managed to create such a function and ask yourself: what should happen when somebody passes it an `Ok` value? I know you said it shouldn't compile, but remember: it may not even be known at compile time whether a particular value would turn out to be `Ok` or `Error`. It could be coming from user input, or from file, or from network, or from random generator, etc. The compiler can't make a compile-time decision based on information that is not known at compile time.

However, based on your clarification in the second half of your question, it seems that what you *actually* want is to take a list of `Result`s and then treat them differently depending on whether there are any errors. And *that* can be quite easily accomplished.

First, let's start with a function that combines two `Result` values in such a way that `Error` subsumes `Ok`:

```
// A stand-in for your result merging function
let mergeSomehow = (+)

let combineTwo a b = 
    match a, b with
    | Ok x, Ok y -> Ok (mergeSomehow x y)
    | Error x, Ok _ -> Error x
    | Ok _, Error y -> Error y
    | Error x, Error y -> Error (x + y)
```

Let's test it out:

```
- combineTwo (Ok 35) (Ok 7);;
val it: Result<int,string> = Ok 42

- combineTwo (Ok 35) (Error "boom!");;
val it: Result<int,string> = Error "boom!"

- combineTwo (Error "boom!") (Error "crash!");;
val it: Result<int,string> = Error "boom!crash!"
```

And now all that's left to do is to keep merging subsequent elements of the list one by one. This is what `fold` does:

```
let mergeAll results = results |> List.fold combineTwo (Ok 0)
```

Let's test it out:

```
- mergeAll [Ok 35; Ok 5; Ok 2];;
val it: Result<int,string> = Ok 42

- mergeAll [Ok 35; Error "boom!"; Ok 2];;
val it: Result<int,string> = Error "boom!"

- mergeAll [Ok 35; Error "boom!"; Ok 2; Error "crash!"];;
val it: Result<int,string> = Error "boom!crash!"
```

For every element of the list, if it's `Ok`, the `combineTwo` function adds it to (or "merges with") all of the `Ok`s accumulated so far, and if it's `Error`, it throws away all the accumulated `Ok`s and returns `Error`, and on every subsequent step that `Error` persists, no subsequent `Ok`s matter anymore.

Comment: Thank you for answering both questions! It hurts to see how much over(or under)thinking I did..